# Issues Connecting Ubuntu 10.4 to MS SQL DB thru Java

Tags: java, sql-server, ubuntu

What is the best way to allow a Java Application to connect to a MS SQL database in Ubuntu.  I am currently trying jTDS but can not seem to get the connection to the server established.

Comment: What problems are you having with jTDS - what are you trying, what errors are you getting, etc.? TCP or named pipes? Can you definitely connect to the database from another Windows machine i.e. do you have the ports opened and not firewalled off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would probably to go with Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver 1.0

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=e22bc83b-32ff-4474-a44a-22b6ae2c4e17&displaylang=en

It's a very simple setup with some very nice documentation. Also, if  your using a server name rather than an ip, make sure you have the FULL servername. For example abc123.thealphabet.com rather than just abc123. Hope this helps!

Comment: Installed and had some issues at first, you were spot on about the fully qualified name, once i fixed that it worked flawlessly!!!  Thanks